# Multiple instances of a struct containing an array with different lengths which are known at compile time

Tags: c, arrays, struct

What I'd like to accomplish is to have a single struct declaration that can be used multiple times with changes only in its array member length in C.

I know this can be done through flexible array member, but this would allocate memory at run time.

I would like to know if it's **possible** to declare a struct, which contains an array the size of which is unknown at **declaration** but **known at compile time** because of its definition, making it possible to have static allocation of the memory used by each instance of the struct. If it's not possible that's good and I learned something new.

My explanation is a bit cumbersome, I know, so I might make a pseudocode example to show what I mean.

**This is not how it works but an example of what I'd like to do**

```
//file1.h
struct my_struct {
    uint8_t char_member;
    uint8_t array_member[]; //unknown length declaration
}
void function(struct my_struct, uint8_t array_size);

//file1.c
//random function for illustration purposes
void function(struct my_struct structure, uint8_t array_size){
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
        structure.array_member[i] = 0;
    }
    return;
}

//fubar.h
extern struct my_struct foo; //still unknown length, but needed for fubar.c to aknowledge its existence.

//fubar.c

#include "file1.h"
#include "fubar.h"

//first instance of my_struct
struct my_struct foo {
    char_member = 1;    //random member definition
    array_member[64];   //definition/re-declaration of foo's array member. Here, I think, it's where it gets ugly
} 

//second instance of my_struct
struct my_struct bar {
    char_member = 23;
    array_member[128]; //definition/re-declaration of bar's array member.
} 

function(foo, 64);
function(bar, 128);
```

the point here is that I can make `my_struct` as an argument for a function and not worry about declaring different functions and struct types for every array size I plan to use. I can use a `void *` as the function parameter but that would defeat type checking, having to pass exactly the type of struct I want. The only way I can think of doing it is to declare struct with a pointer as a member and then define arrays which are "linked" to the pointer in the struct instance, this method would be a bit awkward but would it work?

Context: I'm working in an embedded system and dynamic allocation is something I'd like to avoid. About exposing the struct outside the source file through interfaces, although very good in principle, consume valuable stack space (i.e. I can't call many functions one on top of the others). 
The real-life goal I'm working on is to create some buffers. As an exercise I'm trying to make such buffers in a way that can be wrapped in a library and then used for different projects.
Language is plain C, dialect is c99, compiler is GCC, target is an arm cortex-m3.

Comment: Please use standard terms. `uint8_t array_member[]` is a _flexible array member_ (FAM).

Comment: edited to reflect correct term, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with C preprocessor. For example:

```
//file1.h
struct my_struct {
    uint8_t char_member;
    uint8_t array_member[1];
};
#define my_struct_p(x) ((struct my_struct *)(x))

#ifndef concat
#define xconcat(a,b) a##b
#define concat(a,b) xconcat(a,b)
#endif

#define _TAG_MY_STRUCT(N) concat(my_struct,N)
#define _TYPENAME_MY_STRUCT(N) struct _TAG_MY_STRUCT(N)
#define _STRUCT_MY_STRUCT(N) \
    _TYPENAME_MY_STRUCT(N) { \
        uint8_t char_member; \
        uint8_t array_member[N]; \
    }

// Predeclared structures
_STRUCT_MY_STRUCT(32);
_STRUCT_MY_STRUCT(64);
_STRUCT_MY_STRUCT(128);

extern void function(struct my_struct *, uint8_t);

//file1.c
//random function for illustration purposes
void function(struct my_struct *structure, uint8_t array_size)
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < array_size-1; i++){
        structure->array_member[i] = 0;
    }
    return;
}

//fubar.h
extern _TYPENAME_MY_STRUCT(64) foo; 
extern _TYPENAME_MY_STRUCT(128) bar; 

//fubar.c
#include "file1.h"
#include "fubar.h"

//first instance of my_struct
_TYPENAME_MY_STRUCT(64) foo;

//second instance of my_struct
_TYPENAME_MY_STRUCT(128) bar;
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of macros but this looks neat! it does essentially what I don't want to do (declaring multiple structs, one for every array size) but behind the scenes, I like that. What's the purpose of `#define my_struct_p(x) ((struct my_struct *)(x))`? is it to cast _foo_ making it a `my_struct` pointer instead of a `my_struct64` when passing it to the function? it works like that: `function(my_struct_p(&foo))` ?

Comment: Yes, you understand right, only for cast to struct my_struct.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I can think of is using something like arrays of `sizeof(struct my_struct) + number_of_bytes_for_array` bytes, and using pointers to this array as pointers to the structure.

Something like

```
char foo_array[sizeof(struct my_struct) + 64];
struct my_struct *foo = (struct my_struct *) foo_array;
```

---

Could be used something like this:

```
//random function for illustration purposes
void function(struct my_struct *structure, uint8_t array_size){
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
        structure.array_member[i] = 0;
    }
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    char foo_array[sizeof(struct my_struct) + 64];
    struct my_struct *foo = (struct my_struct *) foo_array;

    function(foo, 64);
}
```

Comment: No problem here because the struct only contains bytes or arrays of bytes. But in a more complex use case, couldn't a problem of alignment arise?

Comment: @SergeBallesta As long as the array member is *last* it should not be a problem, because the `sizeof(struct my_struct)` includes padding.

Comment: can I ask for a bit of expansion on how to use it? an example would be terrific for me to understand it!

Comment: @zakkos Added example using (a slightly modified version of) your "random function for illustration purposes". Note the change in argument type for the structure, as well as the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions that rely only on the C standard, and then there are a number of solutions that rely on known GCC behaviour.

One standard C approach is to separate the data out from the structure, and use a macro to declare it at compile time. For example:

```
struct buffer {
    const uint8_t  size;
    uint8_t *const data;
};

#define STATIC_BUFFER(varname, bufsize) \
    static uint8_t  buffer_data_ ## varname[bufsize]; \
    static struct buffer  varname = { .size = bufsize, \
                                      .data = buffer_data_ ## varname }
```

If you then want a 16-byte static buffer named `foo`, and a 32-byte one named `bar`, you use

```
STATIC_BUFFER(foo, 16);
STATIC_BUFFER(bar, 32);
```

The downside is the extra pointer dereference.

---

Another approach with standard C is to use a preprocessor macro for the buffer size. This not only saves the pointer dereference, but the buffer size is only known at compile time, and thus you save the member in the structure:

```
#define MERGE(a,b) a ## b

#define STATIC_BUFFER(varname) \
    static uint8_t  MERGE(varname, _data)[MERGE(varname, _size)]
```

The `STATIC_BUFFER(varname)` macro declares the array with size defined by a previously defined preprocessor macro, `varname_size`. For example,

```
#define foo_size  16
STATIC_BUFFER(foo);

#define bar_size  32
STATIC_BUFFER(bar);
```

Your buffer-management functions take two arguments instead of one: the pointer to the data buffer, and the size of the data buffer:

```
static void do_something(uint8_t  buf[],
                         const uint8_t  size)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

I'd also use macros to help call such functions correctly. Either

```
#define USING_BUFFER(varname) \
    MERGE(varname, _data), MERGE(varname, _size)

do_something(USING_BUFFER(foo));
```

or, one macro per buffer management function, which looks much nicer too,

```
#define DO_SOMETHING_ON_BUFFER(varname) \
    do_something(MERGE(varname, _data), MERGE(varname, _size))

DO_SOMETHING_ON_BUFFER(bar);
```

---

If you have say cyclic buffers with heads and tails, with sizes powers of two (so you can use the and operator, `&`, to mask the index to stay within the buffer), I would personally prefer the latter one above:

```
#define MERGE(a,b) a ## b

struct buffer {
    uint8_t  head;
    uint8_t  tail;
};

/* Define the size of the buffer, a power of two,
        #define  foo_size  16
   before declaring the corresponding buffer:
        STATIC_BUFFER(foo);
   This yields two variables: foo_info and foo_data.
*/
#define STATIC_BUFFER(varname) \
   static uint8_t  MERGE(varname, _data)[MERGE(varname, _size)]; \
   static struct buffer MERGE(varname, _info)
```

The buffer management functions need three parameters:

```
static void do_something(struct buffer *const info,
                         uint8_t       *const data,
                         const uint8_t        size)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

The interesting thing (with C99) is that you can use `static inline` to suggest to the compiler that that function should be inlined within the code. This approach, combined with the above, yields quite good machine code:

```
static inline void buffer_add(struct buffer *const info,
                              uint8_t              data[],
                              const uint8_t        size,
                              uint8_t              item)
{
    /* Advance head; assume size is a power of two */
    info->head = (info->head + 1) & (size - 1);
    data[info->head] = item;
}

#define FOO_APPEND(c) buffer_add(&foo_info, foo_data, foo_size, c)
```

For example, function

```
void append_hello(void)
{
    FOO_APPEND('h');
    FOO_APPEND('e');
    FOO_APPEND('l');
    FOO_APPEND('l');
    FOO_APPEND('o');
}
```

using GCC 5.4.0 for arm (`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5 -Wall -O2 -S -march=armv7 example.c`) generates essentially (using Thumb instruction set)

```
        .text
append_hello:
        movw    r3, #:lower16:.LANCHOR0
        movt    r3, #:upper16:.LANCHOR0
        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7}
        movs    r7, #104
        ldrb    r2, [r3]        @ zero_extendqisi2
        movs    r6, #101
        movs    r4, #108
        movs    r5, #111
        adds    r2, r2, #1
        and     r2, r2, #15
        adds    r0, r2, #1
        add     r2, r2, r3
        and     r0, r0, #15
        adds    r1, r0, #1
        strb    r7, [r2, #4]
        and     r1, r1, #15
        add     r0, r0, r3
        adds    r2, r1, #1
        add     r1, r1, r3
        and     r2, r2, #15
        strb    r6, [r0, #4]
        adds    r0, r2, #1
        strb    r4, [r1, #4]
        and     r0, r0, #15
        add     r2, r2, r3
        adds    r1, r3, r0
        strb    r0, [r3]
        strb    r4, [r2, #4]
        strb    r5, [r1, #4]
        pop     {r4, r5, r6, r7}
        bx      lr

        .bss

        .align  2
        .set    .LANCHOR0,. + 0
        .type   foo_info, %object
        .size   foo_info, 2
foo_info:
        .space  2
        .space  2

        .type   foo_data, %object
        .size   foo_data, 16
foo_data:
        .space  16
```

in other words, quite nice and compact code. Sure, you could make it even tighter, but it is plenty nice from GCC.

Comment: very in deep answer, i'll just take my time to digest it! Indeed I'm planning on having a circular buffer with write and read heads in a structure.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make use of a `union` containing the structure and a suitably-sized array of `char` to eat up space. The `offsetof` macro comes in handy to set the length of the "space" array. Something like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct my_struct {
    uint8_t char_member;
    uint8_t array_member[];
};

void function(struct my_struct *structure, size_t array_size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        structure->array_member[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum { array_len = 64 };
    union {
        struct my_struct structure;
        char space[offsetof(struct my_struct, array_member[array_len])];
    } foo;

    foo.structure.char_member = 0;
    function(&foo.structure, array_len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it may not the best option, why can't you add another member inside the struct like

```
struct my_struct {
    uint8_t char_member;
    uint8_t array_member[MAX_LENGTH]; //MAX_LENGTH shall be the maximum expected length of array_member 
    int curr_array_length;
}
```

So that for each structure object you create, you can keep track of the array_member size in this curr_array_length variable.

Comment: I suppose it would work but imagine I wanted a char buffer of length 16 and one of length 256. That would lead to 240, very precious, wasted bytes.

Comment: Not sure about what you are trying to mention, the structure memory allocation comes into picture only once you create the structure objects & not during the declaration itself.

Comment: indeed, so at definition time I'd have (assuming `MAX_LENGTH` value is 256) two arrays of length 256 byte, of which only 272 are used (because i actually need only 16 byte of one but the whole space HAS to be allocated). That way the remaining 240 bytes are left there unused and without the chance of being assigned to something else because the compiler thinks I might need them for my `array_member`.

Answer (score 0):

In **C** there's no defined generic types or parametrized types.  Just define a macro to do what you want and reuse it again and again to get the proper definition, as in

```
#define MY_STRUCT(name,length) struct name {\
        uint8_t    char_member;             \
        uint8_t    array_member[length];    \
        int        curr_array_length;       \
    }
```

so you can use it as:

```
MY_STRUCT(struct_64, 64) var1, var2;
MY_STRUCT(struct_32, 32) var3, var4;
```

in your code.  It will expand to something like

```
struct struct_64 {
    uint8_t    char_member;
    uint8_t    array_member[64];
    int        curr_array_length;
} var1, var2;

struct struct_32 {
    uint8_t    char_member;
    uint8_t    array_member[32];
    int        curr_array_length;
} var3, var4;
```